# How to use Xpath and Xquery to extract text() from an attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xmlnode, xml-attribute

Trying to query e-mail addresses using `xpath` and `xquery` but am not getting any results when

simple query:

```
xquery version "3.1";

for $contact in db:open("sample")

return $contact
```

data:

```
<Objs xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04" Version="1.1.0.1">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <MS>
      <S N="First Name">a</S>
      <S N="Last Name">b</S>
      <S N="Emails">a@b;b@a.com</S>
      <S N="Phones">123 456-8904</S>
      <S N="Company Name"/>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="1">
    <TNRef RefId="0"/>
    <MS>
      <S N="First Name">c</S>
      <S N="Last Name">c</S>
      <S N="Emails">e@f.com</S>
      <S N="Phones">123456-3532;563 346-3453</S>
      <S N="Company Name"/>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

I'm looking to get `Objs/Obj/MS/S[N="emails"]/text()` along those lines, for the actual content of the attribute.

Comment: What XQuery engine is in use? Overall, you need to specify path to the XML documents in an XML database.

Comment: I'm using basex, but might try something else.  I think the reference book is general enough to work with most anything.

Comment: BaseX is a great XML database. It supports latest XQuery 3.1

Comment: https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Databases

Comment: Your question is rather confusing, because attributes don't have text node children. You've told us what you want to get by showing us some code which presumably doesn't work, so we have to guess what you intended it to do. The most obvious error is that you're ignoring the fact that the elements are in a namespace; you've also ignored the difference between "emails" and "Emails", and you've used `N` rather than `@N`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your XML database...

You can try something along the following.

**XQuery**

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare namespace ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04" Version="1.1.0.1";

for $contact in db:open("sample")//ns1:S[@N="Emails"]/text()
return $contact
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems, if you want a predicate to check an attribute use `Objs/Obj/MS/S[@N="emails"]/text()` and not `Objs/Obj/MS/S[N="emails"]/text()`. And of course with namespaces and the default settings the path selects elements in no namespace while your document has them in a namespace so you in XQuery you can declare

```
declare default element namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04";
```

and then select e.g. `/Objs/Obj/MS/S[@N="Emails"]/text()` (another slight correction is the string literal `Emails` instead of `emails`.

Note that in XQuery the declared default element namespace is used both for path selection as well as for output elements so you might end up with result elements in that namespace.